# Parse/Swift getObjectInBackgroundWithId query not working

Tags: xcode, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I am trying to run the query to get object in background with ID but when I run the method `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId` , I am getting the error message:

```
"Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type (string, block: (PFObject!,NSError?) -> Void"
```

The same thing happens when I use `user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` so I'm thinking maybe Xcode updated some of the features while using 'block's and now maybe the syntax is different?  Any ideas?

Here's a snippet of my code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEa98.jpg

Answer (score 1):

YES!!! Thank you!

The new sample code for getObject is:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Oaq79bhv53") {
        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
            println(gameScore)
        } else {
            println("error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{(succeeded: Bool, signUpError: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2:**

```
query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "YourId") { (gameScore, error) in
  if error == nil {
    // Success!
    print(gameScore)
  } else {
   // Fail!
  }
}
```

Comment: add context so we can learn from it or you end up in winning the Low-Quality Post Review Award 2019! That gets your answer removed. (End of Review).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just shared the reviewed code from @Marty which works with Swift 4.2.